# Enumerate Iterator to array

Tags: php

So I have these `Generator` objects--you know, the [cool new things in PHP 5.5](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.php) that make lazy enumeration easy.  Sometimes, however, I don't want lazy enumeration: I want to take the data that I would normally iterate over and throw it all into an array--[like LINQ has](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx), but for PHP.

Most of the time I want a generator, but I still have a few times where I need an array.  For example, if there is a possibility of enumerating the data multiple times, and a low chance of stopping the enumeration process before all items have been iterated over.

Is there some intrinsic PHP function that takes an `Iterator` or `Traversable` and outputs an array?  What I really don't want to do is write my own function/method.  Yes, I know, it'd be a short, simple procedure, but I like to avoid having a pile of helper functions scattered about.

Just to avoid the inevitable "use a foreach loop" answer, here's that approach:

```
<?php
function enumerate(\Traversable $iterator)
{
    $array = [];

    foreach ($iterator as $k => $v) {
        $array[$k] = $v;
    }

    return $array;
}
```

I have some other hackish ideas, but what I'm really looking for is a function that doesn't require any additional code, files, or libraries.  Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`iterator_to_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php)

> ## iterator_to_array
>
> (PHP 5 >= 5.1.0)
>
> iterator_to_array — Copy the iterator into an array
>
> **Description**
>
> array iterator_to_array ( Traversable $iterator [, bool $use_keys =
> true ] )

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!  I knew I remembered seeing it somewhere, but it escaped quite a bit of Googling.  Apparently I have to wait 8 minutes to mark this as the answer, though.

Comment: @Zenexer Found it by googling `php iterator into array`

Comment: I think I was focusing too much on `generator` in my searches.  Got too much unrelated stuff.